# I have two breeds of daisies and two breeds of rabbits: How to get one color of rabbit to only eat one color a daisy?

Tags: netlogo

For a class project I am modifying the daisyworld model to have black and grey rabbits within the world. I would like The grey rabbits to eat the black daisies and the brown rabbits to eat the white daisies. However, when I write my code (below) the rabbits are wondering about and not eating the daisies at all and eventually all die off. I am not getting any errors on my code for syntax the rabbits just simply wont eat the specific daisies. Any suggestions on how to get this to happen?

Further info: I have added a boolean for daisy-black. The black daisies are true and the white daisies are false. I planed to have this property as what the rabbits looked for to decide if they should eat the daisy or not.

The "____-rabbit-gain from food" is just the amount of energy the rabbits get from eating a daisy. When inspecting rabbits RARELY does their energy ever go up. Sometimes it does, meaning they found a daisy to eat. But not as often as it should be occurring.

Below is the part of my code telling the rabbits how and what to eat. See any problems or suggestions? Anything is welcome!

```
to go
  ask grey-rabbits [
    move
    set energy energy - 1
    eat-black-daisies
    death
    reproduce-grey-rabbits
  ]
  ask brown-rabbits [
    move
    set energy energy - 1
    eat-white-daisies
    death
    reproduce-brown-rabbits
  ]


to eat-black-daisies ;grey rabbits eat black daisies
  let prey one-of daisies-here with [daisy-black = true]
     if prey != nobody
      [ask prey [die]
      set energy energy + grey-rabbit-gain-from-food]

end


to eat-white-daisies ;brown rabbits eat white daisies
    let prey one-of daisies-here with [daisy-black = false]
      if prey != nobody
      [ask prey [die]
        set energy energy + brown-rabbit-gain-from-food]

end
```

Comment: can you also show the code that calls this procedure?

Comment: Yes I can but what do you mean by "calls this procedure"?

Comment: I added some code. Is that what you wanted? Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with this code. What I would do is open an inspect window for a few rabbits and watch what happens to them. It may simply be that you don't have enough daisies. Also, in the command center, do `count daisies with [daisy-black]` and `count daisies with [not daisy-black]` to see if the daisy colour flag is being set correctly.

Comment: And for future reference, the go procedure is 'calling' the eat-black-daisies procedure because the request to run eat-black-daisies appears within the go procedure. So yes, this is the correct code to show to ask a NetLogo question.